# PostgreSQL: Подсчет вхождений значений в массиве JSONB-значения

Tags: postgresql

В таблице есть jsonb-колонка *answers*, которая содержит массив объектов следующего вида:

```
[
 {
  question_id: XXX,
  is_correct: true,
  created_at: YYY
 },
 {
  question_id: XXX,
  is_correct: false,
  created_at: YYY
 },
 {
  question_id: XXX,
  is_correct: true,
  created_at: YYY
 },
]
```

**Задача 1.** Подсчитать в таблице все вхождения *is_correct: true* (то бишь в каждом элементе массива каждой строки в базе).

**Задача 2.** Найти все строки, где *is_correct: true* и *question_id: XXX*

Помогите. Совсем нуб в Postgres.